# Find the orthogonal trajectory to the family of curves $x^2+y^2=4c^2$ where $c$ is a constant.

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Differentiate w.r.t $x$:

$$x+y\frac{dx}{dy}=4c^2$$

Comment: Your differentiation is wrong.  The derivative of a constant is 0 and you want $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $\frac{dx}{dy}$.  You should have $x+ y\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$.  From that $\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{x}{y}$ and the orthogonal complement will satisfy $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: I would argue the derivative w.r.t $x$ equals $2x + y \frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = 0$, thus $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}=\frac{-2x}{y}$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$x+yy'=0$$ turns to

$$x-\frac y{y'}=0$$ which integrates as $$y=cx.$$

This was expected as the given family is made of circles centered at the origin.